# How to find values in a list that are within 1000 of each other (python)

Tags: python

I have been tasked with a problem to find values in a list of data within 1000 of each other. So far, I have been able to open that data from Excel through Python and print it (without the labels), but now I need some code to print out values that are within 1000 of each other. My code thus far is

```
import pandas as pd
col_list=[0]
new_dataframe = pd.read_csv("~/Desktop/dataa.csv", header=None,  skiprows=[0], usecols=col_list)
print(new_dataframe)
```

and it outputs values from 41182051136430 to 41182098467550 (1255 rows of values). How can I sort through these values and have it print out the numbers that are within 1000 of each other? Thanks.

Comment: You have to solve the logic problem before you can write any code.  What is your algorithm for finding the numbers?  In other words, can you express in plain English what steps the computer needs to take to solve the problem?

Comment: values within 1000 rows? or its difference a-b=1000?

Comment: @SantiagoEchevarria difference a-b<=1000

Comment: @PaulCornelius i am new to python, so excuse my lack of knowledge, but I want to compare the data in this list (there are 1255 rows of various numbers) and see if there are numbers in the list that are 1000 apart or less from each other.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Python specifically. I understand that's what you want the computer to do.  How do you want to break the problem down into primitive logical steps?  Suppose somebody handed you 1255 cards with numbers on them, and posed the problem you describe.  What would you do?  No programming involved, just a task using logic and some grade school math.  Figure that out first.  Then you've got a programming problem and the StackOverflow community can help with that.  You seem to want us to come up with the algorithm and also code it for you.  That's not what we do here.

Comment: @PaulCornelius I see what you mean! I was confused by your original comment, i though you were asking me to tell you what I wanted to do. I will try to write my own steps out and do more research on my own, thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

Import values as a list or array and then do something like this. Not efficient at all but I guess this is what you need.

```
a = [1,2,3,1001,1003]
result = []
for value in a:
    for value2 in a:
        if value - value2 == 1000:
            result.append((value,value2))

print(result)
```

Prints:

```
[(1001, 1), (1003, 3)]
```

Comment: The problem was stated as "within 1000 of each other," which I take mean equal to or less than 1000 between values.  Maybe I'm wrong in my interpretation.

Comment: This is O(n^2).  It'd be better to sort: O(nlogn) unless the inputs are always small.